# Probability that 4 lorries pass a point P

Tags: probability

Alright. They give us a point P which trucks pass at a rate of 3 per 30 mins from the eastside and 2 per 30 mins from the west side. This is a question about linear combinations of random variables, so probably pretty chill for you guys to do.

Question: Find the probability that there will be exactly 4 lorries passing P at a given 20 minute period.

Ok, you see that its an easy question. Here's what I did:
T=Total lorries passing in 30 mins.
E(T)=E(X+Y) where X and Y are the trucks passing from either side. Therefore E(T) =5 per 30 mins. Therefore the average rate per 20 mins is 10/3 trucks. Then I just do P(T=4) in the poisson formula and I get the answer! Yay!

But here is the real question. The question that if answered will completely enlighten me and make my day:

Suppose I didnt want to make things easier with a linear combination. So I break it down into a combinations problem as follows:
1 westbound AND 3 eastbound or 
3 eastbound AND 1 westbound or
2 eastbound AND 2 Westbound or
2 westbound AND 2 eastbound

And I solve the probabilities individually, using the means for 20 mins for the variables seperately. So I sum 4 different equations for example 1W*3E + 2W*2E and so on.

Shouldn't I get the same answer???? Because I don't. I know I am making it harder for myself but for peace of mind it would be awesome to know if I'm missing something.

So the correct answer (which I can get using the standard method) is 0.1835. Try it for yourself. BUT then try and do it seperately and see if you can reconcile the two methods.

Surely the second method, while more convoluted, is also valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include $4$ westbound, $0$ eastbound and $0$ westbound, $4$ eastbound

This will give the following table

```
 numW numE      probW      probE    probWandE
  0    4     0.13533528 0.03471238 0.00469781
  1    3     0.27067057 0.10413714 0.02818686
  2    2     0.27067057 0.23430857 0.06342043
  3    1     0.18044704 0.35146285 0.06342043
  4    0     0.09022352 0.26359714 0.02378266
```

Add up the final column and you get $0.1835082$ as expected

Comment: Thanks Henry. How silly of me to forget those other two conbinations. Good to know that maths still works haha.  On another note. Is there a mathematical formula to compute it? For example 4c1 or something? I don't have my calculator but that's 6 possible permutations, so is there a general way to find out how many? Or is it just intuition?

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \lambda^k \dfrac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!} \mu^{n-k} \dfrac{e^{-\mu}}{(n-k)!} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \lambda^k  \mu^{n-k} \dfrac{e^{-\lambda-\mu}}{n!} =  (\lambda+ \mu)^n \dfrac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}}{n!}$ is the proof that the sum of two independent Poisson random variables is another Poisson random variable with parameter equal to the sum of the original parameters

Answer (score 1):

Take $E(X) = \frac{4}{3}$ for the mean (per 20 min) of trucks heading east and $E(Y)= 2$ for the mean of trucks heading west.

Then you calculate $$ \sum_{i=0}^4 P(X=i)P(Y=4-i) $$

It works out to the same.